# How to prevent input elements from affecting a table's columns' widths?

Tags: html, css

When a certain user action is performed I need to add a row to a table which contains an `<input>` in each cell. I need the `<input>`s to automatically fill the available space *without affecting the column width*.

I need to start with this:

[image: Table without inputs]

And end up with this:

[image: Table with inputs that match their column's width]

But instead, when I insert the inputs every column stretches to a minimum of ~170px (depending on the browser):

[image: Table with inputs that are too wide]

Simplified demo: http://codepen.io/patik/pen/qZXMyL — Click the button at the bottom and note how the original column widths are not preserved once the inputs have been inserted.

I could read the column widths before inserting the inputs and then manually apply `max-width` to each input, however I want the column to remain fluid (that is, the columns should continue to adjust to fit the plain text data). Other rows may be added or removed to the table and I need the inputs to adjust accordingly.

As you'll see in the demo I've already tried creating a `<td><div><input></div></td>` structure in the hopes that the `<div>` would fill the column and the `<input>` would fill the `<div>`, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I'd prefer a CSS solution (even if I need to apply inline styles when the inputs are inserted) but I'd be okay with a JavaScript solution if it's the only choice.

Comment: Which browser do you have the problem? I don't see it, works fine.

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE 11 all exhibit this behavior. However, they all work the way that I want them to using my answer below. (If you saw it working, it's possible you ran the demo during the brief period after posting this question when I put the solution into this demo. I should've created a fork before messing around with it, seeing all the confusion I've caused in this thread.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<input>`s must have a `size` attribute if you want to control their width with CSS:

`<td><input size="1"></td>`

The *value* of `size` doesn't matter (though it does need some value—you can't simply write `<input size>` and have it work). As long as the attribute is present the element seems to respect any CSS I apply to it. In this case, `width: 100%` does the trick.

Demo: http://codepen.io/patik/pen/JXrEGX

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your CSS code:

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Meaning:**

`input[type="text"]`  Select only the input boxes of the type text.

`width: 100%`  The width occupies 100% of the width available from the parent.

`box-sizing: border-box` Make the width also count the border.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVLoYq

Comment: The CSS you posted does not work on its own (proof: http://codepen.io/patik/pen/ONjeEr). After I posted the question I was playing around with it and you just happened to fork the demo while I had the `size` attribute in each input. See my answer below: it's the `size` attribute that enables your CSS to work.

Comment: You changed the HTML inserted by the Javascript script. And it works perfectly without those changes (Like in the link I have posted).

Comment: Your linked demo *does* work, but **not** because of the CSS you posted in your answer. I confused matters by altering my original demo while you were working on your answer—my apologies. Open your link and remove the `size` attribute from the JavaScript functions: the demo will no longer work (all columns get equal widths). My point is that your CSS alone does not work—you must also include `size` in the `<input>` element.

Comment: Yes, the `size` is needed to work. But it gets the job done, why not keep it?