# Bootstrap table columns' width with input element inside

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap `table.table` with columns' width appropriate to the data width:

[image: before adding input elements]

I want to add filter inputs to the table, but it makes all columns to have the same width, and the table itself to be wider than the screen:

[image]

Is it possible to add input elements to the table without changing columns' width? I'm not using any `col-*` classes or any other classes that would affect the `width` parameter. I have only formatted the table with bootstrap `.table` class.

---

EDIT 1:

Adding `width: 100%` to `input` elements helped a little bit, but still not exactly what I wanted:

[image]

I guess the only solution to make `input`s not change column widths is to use `width: 100%` along with explicitly set column widths...

Comment: I'd guess the input elements probably have a default width or min-width set on them. You could set a fixed width on the inputs within the table.

Comment: @BillyMoat Can't find anything like this in element's CSS

Comment: Try css `table-layout: fixed;` and add `table-condensed` class to the table tag

Comment: @pokeybit `table-condensed` and `table-layout: fixed` did not help at all. They only make table more condensed and smaller, but don't do anything with columns width here... :/ I guess I will stick to setting widths explicitly

Comment: Here is the solution:
<input size="1"> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36334325/how-to-prevent-input-elements-from-affecting-a-tables-columns-widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36334325/how-to-prevent-input-elements-from-affecting-a-tables-columns-widths)