# Why do inputs affect table cell widths, making them all equal?

Tags: html, css

There's a table with `table-layout: auto;` and each column can have an input to filter it's contents, these filters are optional so there's a feature to hide them.

Problem is - every time user shows/hides inputs layout of the table shifts and it's irritating. Normally table is wide enough for inputs to fit, so it doesn't make sense why  layout shifts even if inputs have a very small width.

```js
const input_row = document.getElementById('input_row');
const toggle_btn = document.getElementById('toggle_btn');
let shown = true;
toggle_btn.onclick = function toggle() {
  if (shown) {
    input_row.removeAttribute('hidden')
  } else {
    input_row.setAttribute('hidden', '');
  }
  shown = !shown
}
```

```css
table * {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

table {
  width: 700px;
  table-layout: auto;
}

input {
  min-width: 0px;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle_btn">
  Show/hide inputs
</button>
<p/>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Full Name </th>
      <th> Phone </th>
      <th> Id</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="input_row" hidden>
      <th>
        <input>
      </th>
      <th>
        <input>
      </th>
      <th>
        <input>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem, ipsum</td>
      <td>+1 463 123 444</td>
      <td>13 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eaque iure</td>
      <td>+1 999 00 22 333</td>
      <td>37</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Giving inputs `position:absolute;` stops them from affecting layout but introduces it's own set of problems.

Ideally each column would stay the width it was while inputs were hidden, and inputs would fill the available space. Is there a way to do it without controlling widths with JavaScript?

Also I don't understand why it's happening so if you could explain that'd be nice.

**Edit:** this is a table component that has to be dynamic, it's content and columns may vary, so a specific width cannot be set.

Comment: You need to set the width of each col and then it will be static and not change

Comment: Okay, I should specify that this is a component that has to be dynamic

Comment: You can set the width of the cols with % or set min-width if you want them not to change

Comment: Problem is - the columns are unknown, they are set later at runtime.

Comment: its not a problem you can set in the css

Comment: Do you know why inputs affect columns this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36334325/how-to-prevent-input-elements-from-affecting-a-tables-columns-widths), you must use the `size` attribute to the `input` elements. Also, instead of using the `hidden` attribute, you must use a CSS class having the `visibility: collapse` property set when the row must be hidden.

```js
const input_row = document.getElementById('input_row');
const toggle_btn = document.getElementById('toggle_btn');
let shown = true;
toggle_btn.onclick = function toggle() {
  if (shown) {
    input_row.classList.remove('hidden')
  } else {
    input_row.classList.add('hidden');
  }
  shown = !shown
}
```

```css
table * {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

table {
  width: 700px;
  table-layout: auto;
}

input {
  min-width: 0px;
  width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle_btn">
  Show/hide inputs
</button>
<p/>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Full Name </th>
      <th> Phone </th>
      <th> Id</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="input_row" class="hidden">
      <th>
        <input size="1" />
      </th>
      <th>
        <input size="1" />
      </th>
      <th>
        <input size="1" />
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem, ipsum</td>
      <td>+1 463 123 444</td>
      <td>13 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eaque iure</td>
      <td>+1 999 00 22 333</td>
      <td>37</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that not sure is what you meant though

```js
const input_row = document.getElementById('input_row');
const toggle_btn = document.getElementById('toggle_btn');
let shown = true;
toggle_btn.onclick = function toggle() {
  if (shown) {
    input_row.removeAttribute('hidden')
  } else {
    input_row.setAttribute('hidden', '');
  }
  shown = !shown
}
```

```css
table * {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

table {
  width: 700px;
  table-layout: auto;
}
th{
min-width : 100px;

}
input {
  min-width: 10px;
  max-width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle_btn">
  Show/hide inputs
</button>
<p/>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Full Name </th>
      <th> Phone </th>
      <th> Id</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="input_row" hidden>
      <th>
        <input>
      </th>
      <th>
        <input>
      </th>
      <th>
        <input>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem, ipsum</td>
      <td>+1 463 123 444</td>
      <td>13 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eaque iure</td>
      <td>+1 999 00 22 333</td>
      <td>37</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! But this way column widths are not dynamic

Comment: You can also set it with % its just an example.
the thing is if the cols doesn't have min-width or static one so the width is changing depending on the content inside